# THREE.TGALoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Boat modal that is being imported as a JSON. Right now I am trying to also import it's texture map to apply to it's mesh.

The model loads fine, but when I use TGALoader to try to load the texture's `.tga` file, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: THREE.TGALoader is not a constructor
```

I have searched around for any other instances of this and can't find any. I am extremly new to threejs so I'm sorry - this is probably a super noob question.

Here is my code for the `Boat` class:

```
var scale = 10;
class Boat {
  constructor(scene) {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TGALoader();

    // Texture
    var texture = textureLoader.load('models/BW Bandit all in one.tga');

    // Model
    loader.load('models/boat.json', handle_load);
    function handle_load(geom, mats) {
      var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        map: texture
      });
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
      scene.add(mesh);
      mesh.position.z = -5;
      mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
      mesh.rotation.y = -90;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you explicitly include it? `<script src="js/loaders/TGALoader.js"></script>` Also, `rotation.y` is in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to source TGALoader.js loader at the top of your file.

So for example say:

```
<script src="path_to_parent_folder_of_threeJS/threeJS/examples/js/loaders/TGALoader.js"></script>
```